# what to do when a question is marked as duplicate and clearly isn't?

Tags: discussion, support

In the case of [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52430/how-do-i-emulate-the-home-key-on-a-mac-laptop-in-blender/52451#52451), there are 5 moderators marking it duplicate.
The [answer referenced](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124/how-to-emulate-a-number-pad-and-3-button-mouse) doesn't answer the question asked. it concerning completely different keyboard layout than the one being asked about.
Searching for home/end/page up or down does not give any insight to using the Home key on a mac book. Emulating numpad or 3 button mouse will not press home key for a mac user. The information is not provided in the referenced answer.

So, no one is reading what the poster asked, they all just assumed the OP is trying to use the numberpad.

How do I flag as not a duplicate/ needs to be read, not just assumed/ etc?

Comment: I get that on a PC keyboard disabling the NumLock provides a Home key, and thus, emulating numpad would provide that key. But this is not true for mac. mac only outputs numbers from numpad. there is no 'numlock' option. so, just enabling numpad emulation is not sufficient to give access to the 'Home-Key' command on a mac book keyboard. You need to use the mac specific shortcut.

Comment: In the future you can flag the question or bring it up here, pinging people in chat or casting a reopen vote are valid as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"What to do" is bring it up in the meta ;-)

Your FIRST step should be to make sure your question is CLEARLY different (yours is) and comment to that effect (you did). If that doesn't work, bring it to the meta (which you did). These three tools are what StackExchange provides to moderate these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for bringing this up on meta :)

I've reopened the post in question.

Once you have 3000 reputation [you'll be able to cast close and reopen votes directly](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions). Until then, leave a comment and/or post a meta question, just like you've done here.

Also, with the exception of David (note the ♦), all of the users who closed that question are normal users. SE uses a [privilege system](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) which allows anyone to help moderate the site.