# Contacting Moderators

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

I have now been on BSE for a month seriously and haven't seen hide nor hair of any sort of direct message system, a la the one on Instagram or other types of social media. I am aware of the chat feature, but it does not seem tailored to two-person interactions. I think it would be useful to have a way to contact the moderators. That's the end of my question.

However, it did occur to me that both [gandalf3](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/599/gandalf3) and [David](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/2217/david) are quite active on Meta, so I will just say what I wanted to say to one of them here. There is a question I was answering recently: [Add different textures to front and back of plane with solidify?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56823/how-to-add-different-textures-to-front-and-back-of-a-plane/56825?noredirect=1) At first glance, it seemed to bear a great resemblance to the well-known [How can I make a material only apply to a side of a plane?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2082/how-can-i-make-a-material-only-apply-to-a-side-of-a-plane) Infact, the former was marked as a duplicate of the latter. However, as I looked into it more deeply, I realized that it did not talk about the *Geometry > Backfacing* feature, but how that feature is rendered inert when a *Solidify* modifier is used. I posted my answer, which was accepted, and edited the question to bring to light the actual problem.
My point is, **would one of you consider voting to reopen it**? I don't yet have 3,000 rep...

Comment: Drop by chat, our avid users are usually there if you want to reach someone quickly, you can nearly always find at least one of us.

Comment: Also, FWIW thanks to my timezone if it's urgent, spammer or something, you can summon me in minutes with a ping as David said below. I'm pretty much always here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you [can't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/431/278094) privately contact a SE user.

To get in touch with a mod you could:

- ping them in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/the-renderfarm) (both gandalf and I are always "pingable," *did I just create a new word?*, in there). It is ok if you don't want to say *it* in public, there are ways of creating a private chat room for serious issues.
- Write up some question on the meta explaining how you have been using the site for a month, but still cant find a messaging system, then explain the problem. < /jk> Really, the meta is a good place to bring up concerns with the site. We have had this kind of thing here [before](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1073/2217).
- Flag the question "in need of moderator intervention" and write a custom reason explaining what's up (kind of like you did in your question).

It sounds like for this case, casting a reopen vote should of been your first step, well after you get another 106 rep. That would bring the question to the *Reopen Votes* review queue, where other users can vote whether or not is should be reopened.

In any event I reopened the question, so you know at least option #2 works. :)

Comment: +1 for the infinite recursion :D

Comment: @David https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pingable

Comment: @David Thanks! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: @cegaton bummer. but as the saying goes, your never first on the internet.